# Is there any way to get the progress of an XMLPullParser function?

Tags: java, android, progress, xmlpullparser

The parsing takes quite some time, and so I'd like to be able to display a progress bar. However I can't seem to find a way to get the progress to update.
The issue comes from the fact that there doesn't seem to be a way (at least that I know of) to detect how many times `pullparser.next()` will be run. I've tried adding and counting newlines when the data is loaded initially, thought that doesn't give the correct result either.

```
int eventType = pullparser.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        //Do stuff
    }
    eventType = pullparser.next();
    //Update progress by x%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've devised a workaround for the moment, placing here if anyone stumbles to this thread. As long as you keep newlines in the original XML string: If you check that the eventype is text and that it is whitespace, and only increment the counter then, you can work out the progress.

```
private int incrementPullParser(int eventType, XmlPullParser xpp) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT && xpp.isWhitespace()){
                //used for counting the progress
                currentLines++;
                publishProgress((double)(currentLines/maxLines)*100);
                return xpp.next();
            }
            return eventType;
        }
```